# Recommended pine dimensions for desk/shelf unit

Tags: wooden-furniture

I'm looking to make a desk/shelf unit like in the image below. For the vertical pieces of wood (to make the two A-frames) what dimension of wood is advisable?

I would like it to appear skinny rather than chunky so considering using [18 x 65mm pine](https://www.bunnings.co.nz/pinetrim-65-x-18mm-untreated-clear-pine-d4s-per-linear-metre_p00428662). Does this look suitable?

If using this 18mm x 65mm wood how could I attach the horizontal supports between the A-frame vertical sections? To use screws from each end the screws would need to be 65mm (through vertical sections) then ?25mm into horizontal support. This would require very long screws and a long drill bit. Does this sound reasonable? Is there a better way to attach the supports?

Thank you

[image: Example desk/shelf unit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Butt joint like this will avoid any visible screws :

https://www.1001pallets.com/common-wood-joints/

Those pins, having a larger diameter, and glued, will be stronger than screws as the smaller diameter of the screws will likely "rip out" of the end grain.

Or you could countersink the screws and fit covering plugs.

Answer (score 0):

See image below. A joint like this is easier to make without specialized tools, and probably stronger than a butt joint. And as a bonus, the horizontal pieces can act as supports for the shelves or the desktop (green).

[image]

Comment: Also, if you build it just like the one in the photo, it will be liable to rock side to side. You should add some sort of diagonal bracing.